# How to print automatically keyboard input in Chrome OS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-os, chromebook

I am trying to print keyboard input automatically in webpage through java script  in chromeOS/chromebook but not getting the desired output. Any suggestions?

Comment: you'll need to write some code, as there is nothing to do this "automatically"

Comment: @JaromandaX , automatically here means though code(as i am using JavaScript) . Let me know if you have any suggestions to this question

Comment: `not getting the desired output` suggests you've tried something - how about you share it so that this question doesn't just look like a request for code

Answer (score 0):

take a look at keycodes

```
document.onkeyup = function(e) {
  console.log(e.keyCode)
}
```

they map to specific keys on your keyboard. from there you can reduce each key press to each interaction on the board

https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes